# How can I run files on external terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I was trying to make a program in Python that generates random passwords and I wanted to run this program on the Windows terminal instead of the internal terminal of Visual Studio Code.

This is the code:

```
import random

lunghezza = int(input("inserisci la lunghezza della password"))  # insert password lenght

s = "abcdefghijklmnopqestuvwxyz1234567890"

p = "".join(random.sample(s, lunghezza)) 
 # lunghezza means lenght

print(p)
```

Comment: python3.exe yourpythonfile.py ... in a console ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Windows terminal, navigate to the file's directory (you can find it by typing *pwd* in visual studio's terminal) and execute the file typing:

```
python yourfilename.py
```

or

```
python3 yourfilename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute a Python file in a terminal, you have several options:

1-If you are in **Windows**: `python MyPythonFile.py`

2-If you are in **Linux**: `python3 MyPythonFile.py`

If you want to use python 2.x, you need to use `python2 MyPythonFile.py`, in the case that you use **Linux**